# Where can I download an older version of AnythingSlider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, anythingslider

In the [AnythingSlider documentation](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Setup#wiki-version) there is a reference to getting AnythingSlider to work with older JQuery libraries, but I can't find any place to download old versions of AnythingSlider. Anyone know where to find AnythingSlider previous versions?

I would like one of the early versions that worked with JQuery 1.3.2.

*Reasons*

I am forced to use JQuery 1.3.2 on a current project, and have been using noConflict to run it alongside modern JQuery. However I am having problems where some of the modern scripts are not being run at all in Internet Explorer (and only in Internet Explorer). This includes the AnythingSlider. I would like to try running an older version of the slider without the modern JQuery to see if this helps to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/tree/v1.8.6

if you click the button `tag: v1.8.6` and search by `tags` you can browse and download all versions from AnythingSlider

Comment: Note: The AnythingSlider repo has been moved, it is now associated with the CSS-Trick organization: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider