# Why would this AnythingSlider JQuery run in Chrome/Safari/Firefox etc but not in IE?

Tags: jquery, html, anythingslider

My JQuery Anythingslider demo deployment works on all browsers that I've tested, including IE ([DEMO](http://www.steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_anythingslider.html#)).

However, when I attempt to insert it into my site code, which is a mess of a horrible legacy JQuery that I have no control over, the result is that it loads properly in Chrome, Safari & Firefox, but not at all in IE.

To use AnythingSlider, you supply basic mark-up, and the JQuery adds classes & ids to work on it.

Here's the original mark-up:

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li>CONTENT</li>
    <li>CONTENT</li>
    <li>CONTENT</li>
</ul>
```

Here's how my mark-up looks in Firebug on Chrome:

```
<div class="anythingSlider anythingSlider-default activeSlider" style="width: 790px; height: 790px; "><div class="anythingWindow" style=""><ul id="slider1" class="anythingBase horizontal" style="width: 4740px; left: -1580px; ">

    <li class="panel" style="width: 790px; height: 790px; "><img src="img/gallery05.jpg" alt="">
           CONTENT</li>
</ul></div><div class="anythingControls" style="display: block; "><a href="#" class="start-stop" style="display: none; "><span>Start</span></a></div><span class="arrow back" style=""><a href="#"><span>«</span></a></span><span class="arrow forward" style=""><a href="#"><span>»</span></a></span></div>
```

In Internet Explorer 8, on that same page, the mark-up is unchanged from the original- the JQuery isn't running at all, or at least it's not writing any changes onto the slider UL. And of course the slider doesn't work.

*Things I've tried:*

I am using JQuery noConflict to run JQuery 1.3.2 & 1.7 side-by-side. However, when I added the noConflict code to my demo, it still worked in IE, so I don't think it's that.

Changing the page script loading order so that AnythingSlider loads first, older scripts later- no dice.

[Looking for an older version of AnythingSlider so I can run it without noConflict- in progress.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816958/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-anythingslider)

Does anyone know of any Internet Explorer 8-specific behaviours that would stop this plugin from running, and any ways I could structure my page to stop this from happening?

Comment: if you look in the console.  Your `jquery.anythingslider.js` and `lightbox.js` file are never downloaded.  You have the path wrong and should fix it first

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That's on the demo page though and wasn't the problem on my full page, it turns out (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Solved: killed by an errant comma. I was calling my sliders like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider1, #slider2').anythingSlider({
    buildNavigation     : false,
    autoPlay            : false,
    resizeContents      : false,
    hashTags : false,
    });
```

When I removed the comma after false, the problem was resolved:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider1, #slider2').anythingSlider({
    buildNavigation     : false,
    autoPlay            : false,
    resizeContents      : false,
    hashTags : false
    });
```

THAT'S IT. IE was choking on that comma, while no other browser was. Holy mother of a lost Sunday spent figuring this out!